# Instant texture swap in animation

Tags: animation, texturing

I'm animating a face swap in blender 2.8 and I'm changing a mix shader's fac value in each keyframe to swap between faces, but the problem is that each face blends into each other in the animation instead of just swapping as the fac value gradually changes from 0 to 1 instead of going from 0 to 1 with nothing in between.

I'm a beginner in blender, so there is probably a much more efficient and easier way of doing what I want to do but I couldn't find any solution to my problem anywhere.

Comment: Although the proposed answer will achieve what you want, there's something that makes me wonder: if you want to swap instantly, how did you place the keyframes for the mix factor? If you set it for example to 0 at frame 19 and to 1 at frame 20 then even without changing the interpolation there is no gradual change because there is no frame between 19 and 20 that could show any inbetween values...

Answer (score 4):

Open the Graph Editor. You should see something like this, where the curve varies smoothly between keyframes.

[image]

Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all keyframes, then pick Key > Interpolation Mode > Constant from the menu. This switches the curve to jump instantly to its new value at each keyframe.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have solved the problem.